# Custom AOP Spring Boot annotation

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, spring-aop

I am trying to create a custom annotation. I need to understand what's missing.
This is a simple java application.

I have created my custom annotation and aspect. The point-cut, if I am not wrong, is @Before and I am using the annotation at method level.

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Exampleannotate { }

@Aspect
public class ExampleAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(ISTransaction)")
    public Object logTransactionDetails(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) 
            throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("in aspect" + joinPoint.getArgs());
       return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}


@Exampleannotat
public static void add(int a, int b) {
    System.out.println(a + b);
}
```

I expect the program to print  "in aspect" with joinPoint.getArgs() result.

Comment: What is your error message?

Comment: No error message. It doesn't go there at all.

Comment: OK so update this   line @Before("@annotation(Exampleannotate)")

Comment: First of all, please be more careful when asking questions. Is it `Exampleannotate`, `Exampleannotat` or `ISTransaction`? Also, please provide more information, ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I would also be interested in package names for all three classes and the full class (not just a method) including package name and annotations for your application class. There are so many possible error sources, I can only guess. But the thing is, I like to analyse, not to guess. Thanks. P.S.: I have an idea what the problem could be, but want to see the code first.